# Remove certain lines of stroke/line art modifier

Tags: uv-image-editor, toon-shading, lineart

I want to make a 3D model look more like an anime picture, so I added a grease pencil stroke and added it to the collection with the modifier. Now it almost looks good, but some lines I dont want, like the lines on the nose and neck. How can I get rid of those? I tried looking for an editor for the stroke but there isnt one to my knowledge.
Attached is an image of the model and render.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the specifics, but it looks similar to when you have the auto smooth turned on in the Normals tab within the Object Data Properties while using the line art modifier. To keep the good line art mixed with the good shading, just bake the line art , and then turn on the auto smooth

[image]

[image]